# how to remove source using mediator live data when updates are returned by db and network

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, architecture, kotlin-coroutines

I have implemented my network layer using co routines, I want to implement single source of truth i.e. i want updates to be dispatched only from database whenever network calls are made. I came through this article that does the job
https://github.com/Eli-Fox/LEGO-Catalog/tree/master/app

The problem i am facing now is

```
fun <T> resultLiveData(databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>,
                           networkCall: suspend () -> Resource<T>,
                           saveCallResult: suspend (T) -> Unit): LiveData<Resource<T>> =
            liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
                emit(Resource.Loading())
                val source: LiveData<Resource<T>> = databaseQuery.invoke().map {
                    Resource.Success(it)
                }
                emitSource(source)
                val responseStatus = networkCall.invoke()

                if (responseStatus is Resource.Success) {
                    responseStatus.data?.let {
                        saveCallResult(responseStatus.data)
                    }
                } else {
                    emit(responseStatus)
                }
            }
```

this method returns a new object of live data which will eventually be exposed to ui layer which i dont want. I want to put observers in place seperatly and call api method whenever it is required rather than doing both tasks together. Just like in an example below. The ui layer starts observing user live data and only when api call is made changes are delivered to _users which eventually updates user live data

````
  val users: LiveData<Resource<List<User>>>
       get() = _users```
````

Comment: Perhaps you can use a switchmap?

Comment: can you share how can i use switch map?